# How can I reproduce the physics that we can see in Dawn of Titans?

Tags: collision-detection, physics, rts

I'm working on a hobby RTS project and I want to implement collision physics between soldiers like in the mobile game Dawn of Titans.

Here is a video reference https://youtu.be/Fnpot2NeJl8?t=341

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hey, I modified the question to remove the off-topic parts: we don't allow questions such as "how did they do it" because it would be pure speculation; you can ask how can _I_ do as they did?

Comment: Also, please assume that readers did not play the game you're trying to reproduce. You should add a link to a youtube video (with the proper time) illustrating exactly what you'd like to have.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I added a video reference. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: And thanks for adding the link, it really helps understand the question :)